# PBR textures appearing as solid colour

Tags: texturing, shader-nodes, pbr

[image]whenever i use PBR textures the texture never appears? it’s just a solid colour. I have tried multiple things including re-downloading Blender but nothing seems to work… I am very new to blender and would appreciate some help[image]

Comment: Just a note, it helps to answer your question if you post a screenshot of the whole screen. -- About your problem: are you in the *Material Preview* or *Render* mode? (key Z)